# Masking return values in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that I use the following CSE formula to populate a worksheet with all rows where the contents of column L > 0 in a main data sheet name 'Field renewal overview'.  I copy the formula down in the target sheet to ensure I get every instance this occurs and use `ISERROR` to mask the `#NUM!` result.

The below is the CSE formula used in column A of the target sheet and it is replicated in column B changing the returned column to 2 and so on.

```
{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('Field renewal overview'!$A$3: 'Field renewal overview'!$T$155,SMALL(IF('Field renewal overview'!$L$3: 'Field renewal overview'!$L$155>0,ROW('Field renewal overview'!$L$3: 'Field renewal overview'!$L$155)),ROW(1:1))-1,1)),"",INDEX('Field renewal overview'!$A$3: 'Field renewal overview'!$T$155,SMALL(IF('Field renewal overview'!$L$3: 'Field renewal overview'!$L$155>0,ROW('Field renewal overview'!$L$3: 'Field renewal overview'!$L$155)),ROW(1:1))-1,1))}
```

I am sure there is a more efficient/effective method to achieve what I am doing however I am not proficient in VBA to write a script, and the data in 'Field renewal overview' can change meaning that I need to dynamically update the target sheet. I have found some simple VBA scripts that I can modify easily enough to copy the rows to the target sheet however I have no idea how to change them to work dynamically on changes to 'Field renewal overview' etc.

The CSE formula does almost exactly what I want it to do however where no data exists in the returned cell (which does occur), it is populated with a 0.

I want to find a way where that 0 is left as a blank cell. (I had thought of using conditional formatting to change the text colour of 0's to white however I'll be running conditional formatting to alternate row colours instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom format with this formatting string:

```
0;-0;;@
```

The syntax for formatting strings in the Custom format is

```
format for positive;format for negative;format for zero;@ to show text
```

That means, if you only specify a format for positive and negative values, no format for zeroes and allow the display of text with the @ sign, then no zeroes will show. Omit the @ sign and text will be hidden, too. If you don't want to show any numbers, just text, use the string `;;;@`. If you want to hide all contents with formatting, use `;;;`.

The format `0;-0;;@`  has been applied to cells A4 to A8, which pull cells A4 to A8 from sheet 1. Cell `Sheet1!A8` is empty, hence the formula returns a zero.

[image]

Another option is to suppress zeroes with the Excel options. File > Options > Advanced > Section "Display options for this worksheet" > untick "Show a zero in cells that have zero value", but that will apply to the whole sheet, and maybe you want to show zeroes in some other cells.

Comment: Thanks @teylyn - works perfectly. Very much appreciated.